# can Facebook Messenger bot chat with different business pages through single app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a condition where I need to implement the facebook messenger bot to chat with different business pages created by different users, I am not getting any idea how to implement this, could anyone please suggest me is there any way to implement this?

I have done it for single business pages?
I am using `gem 'messenger-bot'` for the Facebook Messenger bot implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In the settings for your app, under webhooks, select the Page you want to subscribe the app to then click the 'subscribe' button. You can repeat this for multiple Pages. You'll need the proper Page role for the Page to appear in the list.

Comment: I am doing exactly in the same way but I have to do some manual work like I need the page_access_token for each page because graph.facebook.com API using page access token to send the response to Messenger user so now I have created a hash to save the page access token based on page id and then get the page access token, but I wanted to get the page_access_token dynamic?

Comment: You can generate a page access token with the graph api and a user access token, assuming the user token has the correct page permissions https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#page-access-tokens